# My Expo Go App crashes after taking picture

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Below is my code. Whenever I take click the button to take a photo, the Expo Go app just crashes. I have tried everything and I just can't figure out why it is crashing. If anyone is able to help diagnose the problem as to why the App keeps crashing please let me know.  I understand I can change it so the user takes a photo outside the app but I really do not want to do that. If there is any way that I can have the camera in app that would be fantastic.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, View } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import { auth, db } from '../firebase';
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Feather from '@expo/vector-icons/Feather';
import FontAwesome5 from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import Octicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Octicons';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Add = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [cameraRef, setCameraRef] = useState(null);
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [selectedPage, setSelectedPage] = useState('Add');

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef) {
      try {
        let newPhoto = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync();
        cameraRef.pausePreview();
        const storage = getStorage();
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        const photoRef = ref(storage, `images/${user.uid}/${timestamp}.jpg`);
        const response = await fetch(newPhoto.uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        await uploadBytes(photoRef, blob).then(async (snapshot) => {
          const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
          setPhoto(downloadURL);
          navigation.navigate('Caption', { photoUrl: downloadURL });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error taking or uploading picture: ", error);
      }
    }
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.cameraui} ref={setCameraRef}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          {!photo && (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePicture} style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Take Picture</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
      </Camera>
      <View style={styles.bottomNav}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
          <Octicons name="home" size={25} color="black" />
          {selectedPage === 'Home' && <View style={styles.activeDot} />}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Search')}>
          <Ionicons name="search" size={25} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Add')}>
        <View style={styles.plusCircle}>
            <Octicons name="plus" size={25} color="white" />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Inbox')}>
          <Feather name="inbox" size={25} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
          <FontAwesome5 name="user" size={25} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Add;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  bottomNav: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: height*.05,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingTop: 10,
    height: height * 0.08,
    width: width*.9,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: width*.04
  },
  activeDot: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: height * -0.012,
    width: width*.06,
    height: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#284F64',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 999999,
  },
  plusCircle: {
    borderRadius: width*.05, // Half of the height and width to create a circle
    width: width*.13, // Width of the circle
    height: width*.13, // Height of the circle
    backgroundColor: '#284F64', // Background color of the circle
    justifyContent: 'center', // Center the plus icon vertically
    alignItems: 'center', // Center the plus icon horizontally
  },
  cameraui: {
    width: width * 0.9,
    height: height * 0.75,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```